# how to store elements in array but by trucating leading zeros

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

```js
function getResult(exp)
{
  var result, num = [], signs = [];
    //console.log("here" + exp.lastIndexOf(""));
  parts = exp.split(/([+-/*])/);
  for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
  {
   var item = parts[i].trim()
   if (isNaN(item))
   signs.push(item);

   else
   num.push(item);

  }
  console.log(num);
}

function maincalculation()
{
   var txtprint = document.getElementById("texa");
   if(!document.getElementById("texa").value)
   {
   }
   else
   {
     var result = getResult(txtprint.value);
     txtprint.value = result;
   }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div class = "textbox">
    <!-- <input type="text" value="" id="tex" />
   <input type="button" value="equal" onclick="equal()" id="add" />
   <input type="button" value="click-count" onclick="click()" id="click" />
   <p><input type="button" name="button" value="Saying Hello" id="hello" onclick="hello();"/></p> -->
   <br><br>
   <input types="text" id="texa">
   <input type = "button" value = "calculate" onclick="maincalculation()" />
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My code contain text-box it takes the whole String type by the user now i want to store the array elements separately in array. it stores perfectly as it is but i want to store array elements like by truncating leading zeros i have use regex function num = num.replace(/^[0]+/g,""); it eliminate all the leading zeros as i want but when user type only 0 it will eliminate 0 value too and stores the blank so is there any way that if user type suppose like [10+30+001+08*0/89] then this value must be store like this [10+30+1+8*0/89] truncating all leading zeros but not the single zero value.

Comment: i have also tried regex function num = num.replace(/^[0]+/g,"0"); but still does not work for me

Comment: Try this regex  `/^[0]+(?=[1-9]|$)/g`.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia That would turn e.g. `001` to `01` if replaced by `0`. If replaced by `''` it would turn `0` into `''`.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia /^[0]+(?=[1-9]|$)/g this not worked :( too please can anyone show me e.g. with snippet !!!!

Comment: Try with this: `/^[0]*(?=[0-9])+/g`. Replace with nothing `''`.

Comment: please guys show me with proper example which is working and also suit for my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for my comment:

```js
var regex = new RegExp('0*(?=[0-9])+', 'g');

console.log('0'.replace(regex, ''));     //0
console.log('0000'.replace(regex, ''));  //0
console.log('01'.replace(regex, ''));    //1
console.log('00106'.replace(regex, '')); //106
console.log('4'.replace(regex, ''));     //4
console.log('10+30+001+08*0/89'.replace(regex, ''));

function getResult(exp) {
    var result, num = [], signs = [];
    parts = exp.split(/([+-/*])/);
    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var item = parts[i].trim()
        if (isNaN(item))
            signs.push(item);
        else
            num.push(+item.replace(regex,''));
    }
    console.log(num);
}

function clickMe() {
    getResult($('#calculation').val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="calculation" value="10+30+001+08*0/89"/> 
<button onclick="clickMe()">Get result</button>
```

Comment: can you show me by using my textbox or my snippet where i put this?

Comment: dude please tell me where i put this in my code var regex = new RegExp('^[0]*(?=[0-9])+', 'g');

Comment: yeah dude right but i just want to store that elements in my num[] array not display in a text-box so can u tell me please how just i store that elements in my num[] array

Comment: @ArchanGhatpande The idea of SO is not to get a full answer, but to get enough so that you can implement it in your own code. But I've updated my answer once again and added the numbers to the `num` array.